# Gmail notifications issue with setIamPolicy

Tags: gmail-api, google-cloud-pubsub

I am trying to get the new Gmail Push notifications working as detailed here

https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/push

I have managed to get the pubsub side of it working (created topic, subscription and can publish and pull messages OK) but it fails at the step

**Grant Publish Rights on your Topic**

The client I am using (.Net) does not support the required methods so I am using the API explorer.  Using the Explorer I generate the following Request.

```
POST https://pubsub.googleapis.com/v1beta2/projects/vivid-canyon-90023/topics/iLink:setIamPolicy?key={YOUR_API_KEY}

{
 "policy": {
  "bindings": [
   {
    "role": "roles/pubsub.publisher",
    "members": [
     "serviceAccount:gmail-api-push@system.gserviceaccount.com"
    ]
   }
  ]
 }
}
```

Which yields a response Error of

```
{
 "error": {
  "code": 500,
  "message": "Internal error encountered.",
  "status": "INTERNAL"
 }
}
```

Not sure what the issue is - has anybody had success with setting Publish Rights as prescribed?

Comment: Why does .NET not support the required method?  Hmm, it's possible it's slow getting generated (it's been > 12h now).  Maybe ping the folks that maintain the Google APIs libraries for .NET.

Comment: There is no support for the Gmail Watch Requests either with the latest .Net Gmail API.

Comment: Seems like the publishing of .NET client libraries to NuGet is slow/delayed.  Will enquire.

Comment: That would be good as I think there will be a few others scratching their head without them.

Comment: New APIs are out now on Nuget.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Entirely updated:

I confirmed that calls fail from Asia, while the same calls succeed from U.S. datacenters. We will work on the fix on Monday (June 1, 2015).

We have rolled out the fix for this, and it should work just fine now (9:00AM Pacific June 1, 2015).

Sorry for the trouble.

Comment: Glad it worked for you TM.  created new topic - same 'internal error'.  Tried against a different project with a new topic still getting the 'internal error'

Comment: Hmm, can you paste the output of the APIs explorer?

Comment: {
 "error": {
  "code": 500,
  "message": "Internal error encountered.",
  "status": "INTERNAL"
 }
}

Comment: can you also paste the request part?

Comment: POST https://pubsub.googleapis.com/v1beta2/projects/vivid-canyon-90023/topics/iLink:setIamPolicy?key={YOUR_API_KEY}
 
{
 "policy": {
  "bindings": [
   {
    "role": "roles/pubsub.publisher",
    "members": [
     "serviceAccount:gmail-api-push@system.gserviceaccount.com"
    ]
   }
  ]
 }
}

Comment: What is your topic name?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79234/discussion-between-takashi-matsuo-and-pnc).

Comment: What exactly is the _answer_ here?  err what was the problem?  :)

Comment: Eric, I reproduce the issue. As far as I tested,  setIamPolicy calls from Asia fail, while calls from US succeeds.

Comment: This is now working for me - confirmed could pull messages from Gmail Notifications.

Answer (score 0):

Your role looks wrong, it should be "roles/pubsub.publisher" (missing the "pubsub.") as per the docs there:
https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/push#pubsub_setup

Comment: Sorry - had been trying different roles - get the same error with the correct "roles/pubsub.publisher" role.

Comment: Using APIs explorer there's a couple gotchas.  Make sure you check the "Use oauth2" box.  Also the user you're logged in as, needs to have admin privs on the developer console project you specify in the "resource" field of the setIamPolicy.  I do know it does work though using APIs explorer as long as you can get the request right (it's a bit hard building it in the UI).

Comment: I've met those criteria so am a bit puzzled.  The topic is right as if I get it wrong it throws another error.  I've found some source for a later pubsub .net library so will try and compile that and see if it makes a difference.

Comment: Yeah it's a bit odd.  Are you able to do topics.getIamPolicy(), topics.create() or topics.list() via APIs explorer and get expected results, etc?

Comment: topics.list() is fine.